# Where is my Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios

Here are two screenshots, my Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

And my emulator:

[image: Emulator]

I have localized the problem further.  I have a login screen which I show if the user is not logged in.  the navigation bar is not visible only after login:  I suppose it has to do with the way I switch from login screen to the root view controller.  Here is the way I do it:

```
func switchToMainScreen() {
    let rootController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeView");
    self.presentViewController(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Can anyone help me as to why there is no Navbar + Navbar item in my emulator?

Comment: Without code it's hard to say.

Comment: added ViewController.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From screenshot it looks ok. The only thing that I worry about is the navigation bar in your view controller with title as "Title".

Could you please try this:

1. Delete the Navigation Controller from your storyboard.
2. Delete the custom navigation bar in your view controller.
3. Select your View Controller in your story board, then choose
   "Editor" in your menu, then "Embed in" => "Navigation Controller".
4. Finally, in your view controller' `viewDidLoad:`, try the following:

->

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = // Set your right bar button item here
```

**EDIT:** Post OP question update:

Since your entry point is not the story board driven and you have an initial login screen, I would advise you to create your own `UINavigationController` and embedded your storyboard view controller into it and then present it. It must work!!!

```
func switchToMainScreen() {
    let rootController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeView")
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootController)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

PS: Remove the embedded Navigation Controller from storyboard then.

Comment: I have edited my question, the navbar appears when I run my app without login, it seems my transition from login screen back to the navigation controller is wrong... maybe you can help with my edit

Comment: Take a look at my update. It must work for you! @tomislav2012

Answer (score 3):

I can't post comment on your question for my reputation, check "bar visibility" at attributes from your storyBoard.make sure it's checked, maybe it's unchecked.

i can't post image in my answer, see following link for more info:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k4WU.png

tell me the result to check another odds.

**//UPDATE**

I think you need to embed your viewController in NavigationController . I mean:
 delete your NavigationController from storyBoard,
 second select your viewController 
 then from top menu bar select "Editor" -> "Embed in" -> "navigationController"
it automatically create an navigation Item which can contain navigation items.

Comment: 'Shows Navigation Bar' is checked

Comment: I changed the code in my question, maybe this helps

Comment: If I run the app without switching to the login screen first, then the navbar is visible... I think it has to do with the way i switch from login screen back to my navigation conroller... see my code

Comment: set an identifier for the navigation Controller in storyboard and present the navigation Controller not the view controller